# Vectorial product analog operation in 4+ dimensions?

Tags: vector-spaces, products

I am thinking about a such operation. Which it need to have:

- It needs to be $\mathbb{R}^n\times{\mathbb{R}^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$
- The result needs to be perpendicular to the arguments (thus, scalar product need to be zero)
- It needs to be unambiguous.

Does a such operation existing? If not, how were it possible to fill at least 2 of these 3?

Comment: There is a natural way to combine, not two, but $n-1$ vectors in ${\nf R}^n$ to get a vector perpendicular to the $n-1$ given vectors.

Comment: There is a [seven dimensional cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product)...

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Generalizations for (among other things) some details on my comment on combining $n-1$ vectors.